# How to synchronize an ArrayList over a Network?

Tags: c#, zeromq, distributed-computing, low-latency

I would like to synchronize an Object between two apps written in C#.

**Example:** an `ArrayList`

I only want a unidirectional transfer from the server to the client.
Each time the `ArrayList` is modified (one of its element is modified or a new element is added or an item is deleted), the `ArrayList` in the client list must be updated/synchronized.

There could be at max 500 changes/sec. A one second delay is acceptable.

Do you know a way to do that? If I have to code it, I think to use a `MemoryCache` with ZeroMQ library.

Answer (score 0):

> **Q :** <sub>*Do you know a (... way ...) to do that?*</sub>

**A :**
Yes, the concept is doable, both cadency-wise ( `500 [Hz]` ) and latency-wise ( `1000 [ms]` E2E ), supposing no giant mastodon message-payloads nor immense SER/DES/update-related processing gets loaded onto such an E2E-soft-sync-line.

ZeroMQ has many smart tricks, yet a few surprises may appear - like an <sub>(almost)</sub>Zero-latency benefit from smart Zero-copy operations but also a Zero-warranty for a message delivery, giving every message either delivered as an exact binary image of the sent-original, or not delivered at all (saving us from error-recovery of bit-damages & other low-level nightmares - which is also a benefit, yet some need not consider this a plus )

So, conceptually, Server prepares (serialises & annotates, if any rich-formats, metadata, timing stamps and likes wanted) the data-update payloads & sends them to all connected & listening counterparties ( using ZeroMQ self-maintained signalling + transport metaplane - rigth, you may use many SIGs + many TRANSPORT sockets for this, using a mix of any available transport-classes
`{ inproc: | ipc: | tipc: | vmci: | tcp: | norm: | pgm: | epgm: }`,
as gets fit, smart & handy in your actual deployment infrastructure ( be it a physical localhost, or a cluster of colocated VM-s or a Global IoT ... ) .

Receiving clients receive on their own any data-update payload and locally deserialise its content and bear the responsibility to perform its own internal data-sync-update ( so this concept works independently of the original / target platforms' O/S, CPU architecture, machine-code endian-ness, data-structure conventions, all is in your designers' hands.

Only the imagination is a ceiling in what is possible in doing this.